# UITabViewController in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios

I create a project with Master-Detail Application,but i want to replace the master to Tab Bar Controller。just like this:
[image: The Master view is a Tab Bar Controller]

How to realize this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the `UITabBarController` to the storyboard, and set the 'master view controller' relationship between the `UISplitViewController` and the `UITabBarController`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But i want to let Tab Bar Controller is master view Controller.

Comment: That's exactly what will happen.

Comment: I'm sorry,your method is that you let the detail view Controller become tab bar congroller,but i want to let the master view Contoller become tab bar controller.

Comment: No, look closely - I'm dragging from the 'master view controller' row, not the 'detail view controller' row - that one is already assigned.

Comment: Do so sorry,i wasn't notice .But when i drag like what you said ,there was a  wrong as flows:      Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/zhanggui/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEBA893C-5DF5-4A9A-AAAD-D992CAED1185/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/00381D90-1DE3-46A6-9996-07D97D334AEA/Test.app> (loaded)' with name 'TIt-bJ-Hqi-view-AtR-6S-RDw''

Comment: Never mind. That exception is very vague. You should post this (with the necessary details) in a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .